# Taking reciprocals and inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was doing a proof involving a natural number $n$, where I want to show that for all $n$, $2-\frac{1}{n}<2$. I started out the proof by stating $n>0$ then without thinking(since usually when taking the reciprocal you flip the sign) I wrote $\frac{1}{n}<0$. I had been doing basic $\delta, \epsilon$ proofs, where proving the implication, relied on flipping the inequality. Is the only case where you don't flip the inequality when taking a reciprocal when $n>0$ or $n<0$. Would a way to get around this be to try avoid taking reciprocals when solving these basic inequalities, and just starting out by observing $\frac{1}{n} >0$?

Comment: If $n$ is positive, then $1/n$ is positive.

Comment: taking reciprocals are *way* easier than multiplying $n$ on both sides (because you don't know whether $n$ is positive or negative)

Comment: Note:  if $n>\color{red}1$ then $\frac1n<1$;  and what do you mean $\frac1n\in\Bbb N\;??$

Comment: True. I was just really confused trying to prove if $y<2-1/n$ then $y<2$. I did it by the following:$1/n>0 \implies -1/n<0 \implies 2-1/n<2 \implies y<2$ I made a mistake first considering $n>0$ and said (taking reciprocal flipping sign) $1/n<0$ which left me very confused on when you should flip the inequality sign.

Comment: you should flip the inequality sign when you multiply both sides by something negative

Comment: My issue is this situation $4<5 \implies 1/4>1/5$ there were no negatives involved and I had to flip the inequality sign However $5>0 \implies 1/5>0$ I guess its because you cannot take a reciprocal of $0$

Comment: Multiply both sides of $4<5$ by $\dfrac1{20}$, which is positive, to get $\dfrac15<\dfrac14$

Comment: True It seems your'e telling me avoid taking reciprocals and flipping signs when solving inequalities. And reciprocals are kind of against the axiomatic properties of these number systems in the first place

Comment: Also, if $n>0$ and $\dfrac1n<0$ then we would have $n\times\dfrac1n<0$, i.e., $1<0$, a contradiction

Answer (score 1):

A  non zero real number and its reciprocal have the same sign. So if for example $n>0$ so is $1/n >0$

Now if you have an inequality and both sides are  positive such that $x<y$ and you reciprocate  you get $1/x>1/y$ for example $3<4$ and $1/3>1/4$

Same goes if both are negative. For example $-5<-4$ and $-1/5>-1/4$

If one is negative and the other is positive, the orientation does not change. For example $-4<3$ and $-1/4 <1/3$

Comment: This explanation is greatly appreciated

Comment: @user707991 Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Comment: @user707991, it would be nice to mark the question as an answer if it has answered your inquiry.